# How to do deep copy for the below class in Java

Tags: java

Look at this class. I get the below class from a great book, "On Java", but how can I deep copy the class?

```
 public class Snake implements Cloneable {
    private Snake next;
    private char c;

    public Snake(int i, char x) {
        c = x;
        if(--i > 0)
            next = new Snake(i, (char)(x + 1));
    }

    public void increment() {
        c++;
        if(next != null)
            next.increment();
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        String s = ":" + c;
        if(next != null)
            s += next.toString();
        return s;
    }

    @Override public Snake clone() {
        try {
           Snake snake = (Snake) super.clone();

            return snake;

        } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake s = new Snake(5, 'a');
        System.out.println("s = " + s);
        Snake s2 = s.clone();
        System.out.println("s2 = " + s2);
        s.increment();
        System.out.println(
                "after s.increment, s = " + s);
        System.out.println(
                "after s.increment, s2 = " + s2);

    }
}
```

Comment: The class run result as below:                                                                                                    
`s = :a:b:c:d:e                                                                                                                                      
s2 = :a:b:c:d:e
after s.increment, s = :b:c:d:e:f
after s.increment, s2 = :a:c:d:e:f`

Comment: You need to set the snake's `next` snake to be a clone of the original's `next` snake, if it is not null.

Comment: I would say a clone of the current `Snake` would be `return new Snake(c, next);`. I guess you are missing that constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

```
@Override
public Snake clone() {
    return  new Snake(getLevel(), c);
}

private int getLevel() {
    int i = 1;
    Snake current = this;
    while (current.next != null) {
        i++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return i;
}
```

#### Solution 2

Create a constructor

```
private Snake(char c, Snake ob) {
    this.c = c;
    if (ob.next != null) {
        this.next = new Snake(ob.next.c, ob.next);
    }
}
```

The *clone* method:

```
@Override
public Snake clone() {
    return new Snake(c, this);
}
```

#### Solution 3

```
@Override
public Snake clone() {
    Snake deepCopy;

    try {
        deepCopy = (Snake) super.clone();

        Snake current = this;
        Snake deepCopyNext = deepCopy;
        while (current.next != null) {
            deepCopyNext.next = new Snake(0, current.next.c);
            deepCopyNext = deepCopyNext.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return deepCopy;
}
```

#### Solution 4 ([Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) Lang)

The class must implement `java.io.Serializable`

```
public class Snake implements Cloneable, Serializable
```

The *clone* method:

```
@Override
public Snake clone() {
    return org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(this);
}
```

#### Solution 5 (JSON serialization with [Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson))

```
@Override
public Snake clone() {
    com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(this), Snake.class);
}
```